# How to rewrite the below code using fetch API for chrome v3 extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

As chrome extension is no longer accepting extensions with V2 manifest, i am rewriting the extension code for V3. As chrome documentation mentions to Replace XMLHttpRequest() calls from background script to to global fetch().Can anyone please help me in rewriting the this entire function using fetch API.

Below is my Code.

```
function createHTTPConnection(serverPortNum, ReqType, JsonPOSTData) {
    if (serverPorts[serverPortNum] == undefined) {
        return;
    }

    var data_file = serverPorts[serverPortNum] + ReqType;

    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        //  Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        //  For Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //  If open fails for first port  then try for other ports
    http_request.open("POST", data_file, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    if ("HistoricalTrackersData" == ReqType || "ExtSett" == ReqType || "RegExp" == ReqType || "BlckTrkRpt" == ReqType || "WhiteListUrl" == ReqType) {
        http_request.send(JsonPOSTData);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    //
    //  Wait for response from server
    //
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //alert("this.responseText " + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
        //  readyState = 4 means request has finished and response is ready.
        if (this.responseText.length) {
            if (this.responseText.indexOf("Request") < 0) {
                switchPort();
            }
        }

        //  Server sends ReadyState = 4 and Status = 200
        if ((4 == this.readyState) && (200 == this.status)) {
            if (this.responseText) {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                if (jsonObj.Request.indexOf("ExtSett") >= 0) {
                    serverPortNumber = serverPortNum;
                    //chrome.storage.local.remove("ExtSett");
                    chrome.storage.local.set({ "myPortNumber": serverPortNumber });
                    resetSettings(jsonObj);
                    clearInterval(settingIntervalHandle);           //clear old set Interval.
                    if (jsonObj.QueryTime == 0 && jsonObj.QueryTime != undefined) {
                        settingIntervalHandle = setInterval(doSettingRequest, (15 * 1000), serverPortNumber); // We can also use setTimeout for get setting once.
                    } else {
                        settingIntervalHandle = setInterval(doSettingRequest, (jsonObj.QueryTime * 1000), serverPortNumber); // We can also use setTimeout for get setting once.
                    }

                    if (attemptCount != 0) {
                        attemptCount = 0;
                        createHTTPConnection(serverPortNumber, "HistoricalTrackersData", JSON.stringify({ "Key": "QH00001", "BrowserName": browserName, "IsMandatory": 1 }));
                        createHTTPConnection(serverPortNumber, "RegExp", JSON.stringify({ "Key": "QH00001", "BrowserName": browserName, "IsMandatory": 1 }));
                        createHTTPConnection(serverPortNumber, "WhiteListUrl", JSON.stringify({ "Key": "QH00001", "BrowserName": browserName, "IsMandatory": 1 }));
                    }
                }
                else if (jsonObj.Request.indexOf("RegExp") >= 0) {
                    //serverPortNumber = serverPortNum;
                    //attemptCount = 0;
                    if (jsonObj.InternalErr == 0 && jsonObj.RegularExpression != undefined) {
                        loadTrackers(jsonObj.RegularExpression);
                    }

                    if (jsonObj.InternalErr != 0 && extSettings.InternalErr != undefined) {
                        extSettings.InternalErr = jsonObj.InternalErr;
                        resetSettings(extSettings);
                    } else if (extSettings.InternalErr == undefined) {
                        resetSettings({ "InternalErr": jsonObj.InternalErr });
                    }
                }
                else if (jsonObj.Request.indexOf("HistoricalTrackersData") >= 0) {
                    if (jsonObj.InternalErr == 0 && jsonObj.BlockedTrackers != undefined) {
                        // Listen for incoming messages
                        //alert("hey1 " + JSON.stringify(jsonObj.BlockedTrackers));
                        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

                            // Check if the message type is "send_data"
                            if (message.type === "send_data") {
                                var data = JSON.stringify(jsonObj.BlockedTrackers);

                                // Send the data object to the viewdetails.js file
                                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "data_received", data: data });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (jsonObj.Request.indexOf("WhiteListUrl") >= 0) {
                    //serverPortNumber = serverPortNum;
                    //attemptCount = 0;
                    if (jsonObj.InternalErr == 0 && jsonObj.WhiteListUrl.WhiteListInt != undefined && jsonObj.WhiteListUrl.WhiteListUI != undefined) {
                        whiteList = jsonObj.WhiteListUrl.WhiteListInt.concat(jsonObj.WhiteListUrl.WhiteListUI);
                        whiteList = whiteList.sort();               // Here, we need to sort array for binarySearch.
                    }

                    if (jsonObj.InternalErr != 0 && extSettings.InternalErr != undefined) {
                        extSettings.InternalErr = jsonObj.InternalErr;
                        resetSettings(extSettings);
                    } else if (extSettings.InternalErr == undefined) {
                        resetSettings({ "InternalErr": jsonObj.InternalErr });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((4 == this.readyState) && (0 == this.status))  //  No Response from server
        {
            switchPort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In short it's fetch(url, {method: 'POST', headers: {'foo': 'bar'}, body: data).then(r => { console.log(r.status); return r.json(); }).then(json => { ..... }).catch(err => { ..... }) You need to clarify the problem.